# Textbox that behaves similar to the Multiple Object Selection dialog in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, textbox, custom-controls

Im trying to create an app which has multiple functions similar to Active Directory Users and Computers snap in.

The window i am trying to replicate is the dialog with the "check names" button which makes the text for each user into a single underlined block which when you hit backspace near it, it deleted the whole thing not just a letter.

In the screenshot below, i am looking to replicate the textbox with the underlined group names in it.

[Screenshot of the control i am wanting to replicate.](http://www.winfrastructure.net/blog/image/windows-servers/windows-server-2003/Migration-from-NT4-to-Windows-2003-Active-Directory-domain/11_Group-selection.gif)

Hope you can shed some light on how this control is achieved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to create your own custom control.
Subclass `TextBox` and add the needed functionallty.
Check [this AutoComplete text box](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34785-create-an-autocomplete-textbox-control-in-c#/) and [this user searchable text box](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/SearchableControls.aspx) for nice `TextBox` custom controls that will give you ideas on how to do it.

HTH

Comment: hi there, thanks for the reply. unfortunalty this is not what i was asking. I would like to know how to create the control not the code to check users.

Comment: Do you mean the textbox and the buttons...?

Comment: Mainly the textbox, and more specifically how it (for each object name) creates a "block" of text which is interacted with as a whole and not per character (if that makes sense)

Comment: Sorry, missed the question purpose . Revised.